# Not changing the specified data on update-action

Tags: reactjs, redux

I have an Edit Form in which i can update an already existing element of specified ID.
Let's say im editing this character:

```
 {
      "name": "Walter White",
      "birthday": "1963-01-07",
      "img": "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/0/03/Walter_White_S5B.png",
      "status": "Alive",
      "appereance": [1, 2, 3],
      "id": 1
    }
```

I want to change the name,birthday,image and status. And i already did that. But I  want the `apperance` array to remain the same. Although, after updating the data, the apperance is being erased.
Does anyone know, what can I do so that the apperance array won't change?
My `EditForm` code:

```
const UserEditForm = () => {
  let { id } = useParams();
  const { user } = useSelector((state) => state.user);
  const [state, setState] = useState({
    name: "",
    birthday: "",
    img: "",
    status: "",
    // appereance: ????? 
  });
  const [error, setError] = useState("");

  let history = useHistory();
  let dispatch = useDispatch();
  const { name, birthday, img, status, apperance } = state;
  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(getSingleUser(id));
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (user) {
      setState({ ...user });
    }
  }, [user]);

  const handleInputChange = (e) => {
    let { name, value } = e.target;
    setState({ ...state, [name]: value });
  };

  const handleSubmit = () => {
    dispatch(updateUser(state, id));
    history.push("/");
    setError("");
  };
  return (
    <div>
      <Button
        style={{ width: "100px", marginTop: "20px" }}
        variant="contained"
        color="secondary"
        type="button"
        onClick={() => history.push("/")}
      >
        Go Back
      </Button>
      <h2>Edit User</h2>
      {error && <h3 style={{ color: "red" }}>{error}</h3>}
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        <TextField
          id="standard-basic"
          label="Name"
          value={name || ""}
          name="name"
          type="text"
          required
          onChange={handleInputChange}
        />
        <br />
        <TextField
          id="standard-basic"
          name="birthday"
          value={birthday || ""}
          type="date"
          required
          onChange={handleInputChange}
        />
        <br />
        <TextField
          id="standard-basic"
          label="img"
          value={img || ""}
          name="img"
          type="url"
          required
          onChange={handleInputChange}
        />
        <select
          id="standard-basic"
          label="status"
          value={status || ""}
          name="status"
          onChange={handleInputChange}
        >
          <option value={""}>Brak informacji</option>
          <option value={"Alive"}>Alive</option>
          <option value={"Dead"}>Dead</option>
        </select>

        <Button
          style={{ width: "100px" }}
          variant="contained"
          color="primary"
          type="submit"
          onChange={handleInputChange}
        >
          Update
        </Button>
      </form>
    </div>
  );
};
```

**EDIT ADDED REDUCER**

```
const fetchState = {
  users: [],
  user: {},
};
export const userReducer = (state = fetchState, { type, payload }) => {
  switch (type) {
    case USERS_FETCH:
      return { ...state, users: payload };
    case ADD_USER:
      return { ...state, users: [...state.users, payload] };
    case UPDATE_USER:
      return { ...state, users: [...state.users, payload] };
    case GET_SINGLE_USER:
      return {
        ...state,
        user: payload,
      };

    default:
      return state;
  }
};
export const selectedUserReducer = (state = {}, { type, payload }) => {
  switch (type) {
    case GET_USER:
      return { ...state, ...payload };
    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

Comment: what does your reducer look like?

Comment: @KeatonBenning reducer added

Comment: what does your state look like before dispatching and put a console.log in your switch statement. What do you get from the log?